# Google Drive Api can not list my comments

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to get my comments via the following api(with fileId=xxxx & field=comments):

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list

But it seems likes Google Drive Api cannot list my comments(always 0),

How do I get file comments links from google drive api?

Comment: What file are you passing the ID of, and what type of comments do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide an example request and response?

Comment: gapi.client.drive.comments.list({
          fileId: '1Me8XlR4GoJkQc0tZDR1lsE4lDSr50q-g',
          fields: 'comments',
})

Comment: and the response.result.comments always return 0 elements

Comment: What type of file is that?

Comment: Word. i mean docx or doc

Comment: You can't get them for docx or doc files, only native Google Drive files can have comments retrieved by the API

Answer (score 0):

You can use the driveactivity api instead.

https://developers.google.com/drive/activity

Use a query that filter by comments:

```
self.service.activity().query(body = {'pageSize': 10, 'filter' : "detail.action_detail_case:COMMENT"}).execute()
```

You get update 1000 pageSize, but also get a nextpagetoken incase you need more.